# XDebug is not formatting error

Tags: php, macos, xampp, xdebug

I have installed XDebug on Mac OSX / XAMPP and appears correctly in phpinfo(). But the errors aren't format in the way xdebug used to do (these orange box looked pretty clear).

Some values are correctly set (appearing in phpinfo()):

- display_errors : On
- html_errors : On
- xdebug.auto_trace : On

If I switch xdebug.show_exception_trace to On I see the new informations added by XDebug correctly formated... This is just the basic errors display whose look as not changed. Then I assume that XDebug is correctly started and runnung.

EDIT 1 : Here's the XDebug section of my phpinfo
[image]

EDIT 2 : I've a new fresh and clean installation where this problem doesn't occure anymore.

Answer (score 7):

This made it work for me: [How to enable formatted Xdebug errors and traces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877817/how-to-enable-formatted-xdebug-errors-and-traces)

Basically, just set `html_errors = On` in `php.ini`.

Comment: He just said it has "html_errors: On"

Answer (score 3):

The `xdebug.default_enable` is responsible for improving normal error display - and it is activated in your case, so it should work.

To test if it really works, create a fresh php script with

```
trigger_error('foo');
```

and see if that works. If it does, then probably your application changes the setting.

---

Btw, `auto_trace` does not change a thing for this problem.

Comment: isn't that more of a comment?

Answer (score 2):

I notice you say

> errors aren't format in the way xdebug used to

not that the content is *unformatted*..

I had a formatting issue: **my page's css was nuking the xdebug display!**
as a result, lots of white on white producing bizarre formatting.

I added some rules to [firefox profile]/chrome/userContent.css

```
.xdebug-error {
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.xdebug-error tr:first-child th {
  padding: 20px !important;
}
.xdebug-error tr:first-child th span {
  background: transparent !important;
  color: red !important;
  display: block !important;
  float: left !important;
  font-size: 50px !important;
  padding-right: 20px !important;
}
.xdebug-error tr:first-child th a {
  color: #fff !important;
}
.xdebug-error a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.xdebug-error a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.xdebug-error td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

most of which works; not sure why the :first-child tags fail < shrug >

good luck! Tim

Comment: There's not mention of xdebug in the generated HTML (thus this is not a style problem. I have the standard php error rendering.