# How to enable formatted Xdebug errors and traces

Tags: xdebug

I am not sure when or what I have changed, but suddenly xdebug no longer renders its formatted stacktraces. Instead, it renders the stacktrtace without any HTML; [here is an example](http://berkes.openphoto.me/photo/l/view); Whereas I would expect the orange tables like [here](http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace)

I have searched the documentation, but cannot find any reference to a setting or config that would (un)set this. What did I do wrong?

My xdebug.ini (Ubuntu, so /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini) is small:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so

xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.auto_trace = 1

xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9010
xdebug.remote_host = audrey

; xdebug.profiler_enable = 1

; Markup of var_dump
xdebug.overload_var_dump = 1
```

Comment: maybe you can check and try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78146509/11039697

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Xdebug respects PHP's normal settings regarding error reporting and formatting. In this case, you have most likely "html_errors" set to Off in php.ini. Turn it back to On, and Xdebug should show nice orange tables again.

cheers,
Derick

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ini_set('xdebug.auto_trace', 1);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php