# PHP runtime error

Tags: php, runtime-error, xdebug

I'm programming PHP for some time.

I use an **Windows XP SP3** with **PHP 5.4**, **SQlite 3**, **Apache 2.4** as a development environment.
The remote host server (not mine) is a **Windows Server 2008** with **PHP 5.3**, **Apache 2.2**, **IIS 7.0** and **SQL Server 2008**.

My editor is the simple and wonderful **EditPlus**.

Concerning **Javascript** it's nice because of **Firefox** plus the great add-on **FireBug**, which allows for complete HTML + CSS + Javascript debugging.

My problem is PHP error management in my development environment (my personal machine).

The PHP syntax errors typically appear ok with line number and so on, allowing easy fix. Also there are online tools for check syntax (e.g [pilliap](http://www.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/)) and other online tools to test the execution of PHP snippets (E.g [writecodeonline.com](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) )

However, my curse is runtime errors (eg, uninitialized variable **$ _SESSION**). Sometimes it shows correctly, but other times the error message (including the right line number!) are embedded within the source code, inside spurious HTML tags. Simple tests shows no problem. but my real code generally does.

It is not a situation that does stop me from moving forward, but it is unpleasant.

I did not find any hint on the Internet about this strange behavior and I'm very curious if somebody can give a clue about it.

***My question: How is possible a PHP runtime-error sometimes appears in the browser (as desired in a development environment), sometimes it appears inside Javascript + HTML source code together spurious HTML tags?***

*PS: Is not a question about PHP log files or Display Error setting in PHP.Ini file.*

*PS2: The same situation happens with or without XDebug installed.*

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How is possible a runtime PHP error appears inside the souce HTML code, if there is no echo or print PHP command to do this?

Comment: Depending on your configuration (display_errors in php.ini), errors can be output into the html generated output.

Comment: I with that my runtime PHP error appears in the browser not inside source HTML+JS code, like sometimes happens with me.

Answer (score 2):

Use the php `error_log()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) to show information about your errors the way you want.

Apart from that, have a look at your `php.ini` configuration file. There are many variables (`html_errors`, `error_log`, `display_errors`, `error_reporting` ...) to setup the output of errors as you want so they not mess up the html output.

Comment: I will try. Anyway it is a kind of mistery.

Comment: Mistery? Not at all. If you have "display_errors = On" in your php.ini configuration file, the runtime errors will be output in the middle of the html output, just when they  happens.

Comment: I read error_log() doc. It writes a message in the log file. It don't solve my question because it's easier see my HTML/JS source code, search a PHP error message that contains the line and the error explanation. So I can correct it and runs again. However it's a weird behavior and a clumsy procedure.

Comment: Where I use "display_errors=Off" and restart the Apache Server, it doesn't shows any PHP error. Obviously it's not good practice during the development cycle. I need to see the error, but in the browser (in the beautiful XDebug format) , not inside and hidden inside  source code together with rubbish tags.

Comment: I have never worked with XDebug. Anyway, maybe you find some useful information in this question about PHP and XDebug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877817/how-to-enable-formatted-xdebug-errors-and-traces

Comment: I've disabled XDebug in order to to discover if the problem it would be solved, but that did not happen. So the problem is not XDebug itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `log_errors` and the error log file are for. Just read them and all of your errors are nicely listed.

---

EDIT: You can also drag all errors on the page to be visible with the following:

First, set `error_prepend_string` and `error_append_string` to something noticeable. For instance, you can use `<phperrormessage>` and `</phperrormessage>`. Just anything that is unlikely to appear in your legitimate output.

Then place this at the start of your code:

```
ob_start(function($c) {
    if( preg_match_all("(<phperrormessage>(.*?)</phperrormessage>)is",$c,$matches)) {
      $c = preg_replace("(<phperrormessage>(.*?)<phperrormessage>)is","",$c);
      $c = str_replace(
          "</body>",
          "<div id=\"phperrors\">".implode("<hr />",$matches[1])."</div></body>",
          $c);
    }
    return $c;
});
```

Comment: log_errors is just a setting about log error file. I don't want to see log files.
My question:  How is possible that PHP runtime error sometimes shows in the browser (As desired), sometimes it appears inside source HTML + JS code (Right button in Firefox, option "View Source Code")

Comment: Because sometimes it's in a place that's not rendered. For instance, if you have a `<select>` element taht you populate with a loop, but there's an error there, then the error will be placed in the select and not visible. I'll edit in a possible way to prevent this.

Comment: Great tip, Kolink. Thanks. I will test this stuff I'll post my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Forums and Q&A websites are indeed a great resource for learning! Thanks **Kolink** and **StackOverflow.com**.

From the *Kolink* tip, I've researched a little bit and then I've created a new way to tame the vast majority of runtime errors in PHP.

I have not figured out exactly what is happening, but I've discovered a powerful way to not use the default PHP error-handling and instead collect all runtime error messages in the same place.

Note that the PHP compilation errors are not a problem for me, because any syntax checker solves it, including PHP.exe.

Suppose I have a PHP source code with many potential runtime errors. So I put my code in the following lines inside  HTML tag, e.g. in the initial position that I need use PHP code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var nerrors = 0;               // PHP Errors count in Javascript

 function PHPErrors() {         // Javascript  Function that wraps the PHP Code
  <?php
               // MyErrorHandler is my function that my custom error handler
               // uses with error parameters in that given order.

     function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
     echo "document.getElementById('PHPErro').innerHTML += " . 
      "\"$errno: $errstr ($errline)<br>\";\r\n";        
     echo "nerrors = nerrors + 1;\r\n";
     return true;
 }
      // That's the line the set my custom new error-handling
      // disabling the default error handling
 $old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

      // Below random PHP code full of errors 
 $b = $a;                 // PHP Error 1
 $c = $a +1;              // PHP Error 2
 $d = $a + 1;             // PHP Error 3  
 $e = $_SESSION['glove'];  // PHP Error 4
?>
      // No PHP runtime error deserves a nice messagen
if (nerrors===0) {
   document.getElementById('PHPError').innerHTML =
                    "Well done! PHP without errors."; } 
}                        // End Javascript Function
```

After this code one can put additional Javascript and PHP freely.

Finally I put in my some place inside HTML body part this 2 lines.

```
    <p id="PHPError"> </p>
    <button onclick="PHPErrors()">Show me all PHP runtime errors</button>
```

When I browse this PHP page, I can see this button. So I press it and I can see all PHP runtime error messages or the pleasant **"Well done ... "** message.

Comment: Obviously this suggestion applies just for development cycle.  Production site should give customized message for general user.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've discovered what happens with PHP.

The default PHP error handling generates errors in the body section. With **XDebug** the message is more detailed, but the same situation happens.

So when I put PHP code inside a JS function, before BODY section, this behavior doesn't work, because HTML tags before BODY section generates garbage.

Syntax errors are different because it is a previous phase from PHP interpreter, that is made before running the PHP + HTML code.

Therefore, to be possible to examine the error, In that case you need to look the source code. There will be the spurious tags with the error message.

So my code in other [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358518/how-to-show-all-php-runtime-errors-in-browser-using-javascript) that I've posted in [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) deals with that situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I tried your solution with limited success. I actually like my original error handler - it sends an email. When I used to build pages with just php, I found that I did not need to send an email as the error would just show up nicely. Now that I am moving to javascript rendering of html, the error does not show up, or is hidden. The logging is kinda painful to navigate to, page source is better, but my email is always open. It builds an error message and emails it as well as `echo` the message, but as we know this is dumping to the page source and not showing up or sometimes showing up in bits.

```
function pos_error_handler ($e_number, $e_message, $e_file, $e_line, $e_vars) 
{


$includes = get_included_files();
//var_dump( $includes);
//echo 'WTF';
// Build the error message.
$message = "<p>Nice Job moron: A pos error occurred in script '$e_file' on line $e_line: $e_message\n<br />";
// Add the date and time:
$message .= "Date/Time: " . date('n-j-Y H:i:s') . "\n<br />";
// Append $e_vars to the $message:
$message .= "<pre>Error Variables:<br />" . print_r ($e_vars, 1) . "</pre>\n</p>";
// what is the url?
$message .= "<p><pre>URL: " .getPageURL()   . "</pre>\n</p>";
$message .= '<pre>Session variables:<br />' . print_r($_SESSION,1). "</pre>\n</p>";
$message .= '<pre>Bactrace:<br />' . print_r(debug_backtrace(),1). "</pre>\n</p>";
if (!LIVE) 
{ 
// Send an email to the admin:
    mail(SUPPORT_EMAIL, 'TEST Site Error!', $message, 'From: ' . SUPPORT_EMAIL);
    // Development (print the error).

    echo '<div class="error">' . $message . '</div><br />';


}
else 
{ 

    // Send an email to the admin:
    mail(SUPPORT_EMAIL, 'Site Error!', $message, 'From: ' . SUPPORT_EMAIL);
    // Only print an error message if the error isn't a notice:
    include(HEADER_FILE);
    if ($e_number != E_NOTICE) 
    {
        echo '<div class="error">A system error occurred. We apologize for the inconvenience.</div><br />';
    }
    echo '<div class="error">An Error has occurred and has been emailed to the administrator. Please note the conditions that caused this error and send a note to the administrator</div><br />';
}
//include(FOOTER_FILE);
exit();
}
```