# How to show all PHP runtime errors in browser using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, error-handling, runtime-error, xdebug

Normally in development cycle when one is programming PHP and testing, one sees just one error for each run.

You can see syntax errors using php.exe or using a online tool [pilliapp](http://www.piliapp.com/php-syntax-check/) or  [phpcodechecker](http://phpcodechecker.com/). However, runtime errors, like undefined variable, you cannot detect.

You can use **XDebug** for tracing but it's boring.

**How one can show all PHP runtime errors once in browser?**

So the user can handle all silly problems at the same time, in unobtrusive way. (Not the logical errors).

Comment: I know you didn't ask this, but error handling is (amongst a few other aspects) broken by design in PHP. If you have the choice, avoid PHP altogether.

Comment: Class Stacker, what tool do you recommend instead in the server-side? I don't need to develop big sites because my area of professional performance is business. I like PHP because it's very similar to JavaScript. However, I prefer Visual Basic syntax style using IF .... ENDIF (ASP) with no semi-comma instead IF ( ...) { commands }

Comment: I left PHP alone and went on to Python. I'm not sure you'll love it, though. It identifies blocks by indentation (I guess one can only love or hate that) and the step from V2 to V3 is painful for programmers, at least if one relies on libraries. But it's much cooler and has less severe design flaws thatn PHP if you ask me.

Comment: Class Stacker, anyway I cannot use Python because my host provider ( Windows Server installed) offers just ASC or PHP. PHP is the obvious choice because Javascript is almost mandatory.

I believe that you can has all modern concepts in a programming language, with a more gentle and readable syntax.

The fight between Pascal and C was over and C has won!

the next obvious question: What the main PHP severe design flaws?

Comment: See for example [PHP: a fractal of bad design](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/)

Comment: Thanks Class Stacker. Gotcha! It's a long article. I started to read and I's very interesting. Bother me the PHP weak typing, implicit conversion, many overlapped functions, not intuitive function interface, implicit declaration, etc.
Unfortunately, now I have no option. ASP is also very criticized by the developers community.

Comment: Never mind. I am a computer language purist, and even I have developed a whole website using PHP. For a small/noncommercial site I think it won't hurt too much. It's just that in the medium and long term, if I found myself thinking PHPish, I would see this as a very bad sign. YMMV. ;)

Comment: @ClassStacker - being a lanugage purist is really not very helpful. PHP has its flaws, but so have most other languages. Most of the points in the "Fractal of bad design" post can be successfully counter-argued. But the best counter argument is just not to get too hung up about languages at all. I know I won't change your opinion, and this isn't the place to try anyway, so I'll stop there and refer you to this link: http://michaelkimsal.com/blog/tech-partisanship-doesnt-help-much/

Comment: @SDC Thanks for the nice link. I didn't want to start such a discussion anyway. As I said, I've used PHP myself. I just thought it was good to know that error handling need not be the way it is done in PHP, and Paulo showed some interest. But it's true we should probably not go on here. :)

Answer (score 2):

Forums and Q&A websites are indeed a great resource for learning!

Yesterday I've made a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348252/php-runtime-error/14351468#14351468) in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).com and the discussion inspire me to create a new way to tame the vast majority of runtime errors in PHP using **PHP** and **Javascript**.

Suppose I have a PHP source code with many potential runtime errors. So I put my code in the following lines inside  HTML tag, e.g. in the initial position that I need to use PHP code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var nerrors = 0;               // PHP Errors count in Javascript

 function PHPErrors() {         // Javascript  Function that wraps the PHP Code
  <?php
               // MyErrorHandler is my function that my custom error handler
               // uses with error parameters in that given order.

     function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
     echo "document.getElementById('PHPError').innerHTML += " . 
      "\"$errno: $errstr ($errline)<br>\";\r\n";        
     echo "nerrors = nerrors + 1;\r\n";
     return true;
 }
      // That's the line the set my custom new error-handling
      // disabling the default error handling
 $old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

      // Below random PHP code full of errors 
 $b = $a;                 // PHP Error 1
 $c = $a +1;              // PHP Error 2
 $d = $a + 1;             // PHP Error 3  
 $e = $_SESSION['glove'];  // PHP Error 4
?>
      // No PHP runtime error deserves a nice messagen
if (nerrors===0) {
   document.getElementById('PHPError').innerHTML =
                    "Well done! PHP without errors."; } 
}                        // End Javascript Function
```

After this code one can put additional Javascript and PHP freely.
Finally I put in my some place inside HTML body the 2 below lines.

```
    <p id="PHPError"> </p>
    <button onclick="PHPErrors()">Show me all PHP runtime errors</button>
```

So when I browse this PHP page, I can see

[image: Button to press for seeing the errors]

Finally I press it and I can see all PHP runtime error messages

```
8: Undefined variable: a (26)
8: Undefined variable: d (27)
8: Undefined variable: c (28)
8: Undefined index: glove (29)
```

or the pleasant

```
Well done! PHP without errors.
```

Obviously one don't need any button and it is possible to include this code inside a javascript onload function.

Comment: +1 for being inventive. You might also want to look up [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/), which allows you to send messages from PHP to the Firefox console. You'll still need some code to get it to send actual PHP errors, but the console might be a more friendly place for them than the site itself.

Comment: Thanks SDC. I will read your recommendation ( michaelkimsal.com/blog/tech-partisanship-doesnt-help-much ). I will try FirePHP, add-on for FireBug.(and I love Firebug!)

Comment: @SDC, **PHP** is crazy! My last answer posted in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348252/php-runtime-error/14371274#14371274) comments that default runtime error handling concerning PHP code before <Body> section produces error messages inside rubbish HTML tags (because before <Body>, HTML tags don't mean nothing!