# Showing development php error on page rendered by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I used to render all my html in php and then echo an html string when complete. When a php error occurred in my test site (this is an error during development, like a misspelled variable) I would echo the error and quit. Very easy to then see the error and quickly fix it. When the site is live I would show a generic error and send the error specifics via email. These live errors are less common and an email is perfect.

Currently I am moving to rendering the page using javascript/jquery. Now when PHP error occurs the error does not render on the page. I can get the error via email, but sometimes I am even unaware that an error has occurred. There is no error in the console, and the page, with exception of the header and footer, will be blank.

Consequently, In order to then show php errors I do all my php code first. Errors will show as expected. In php I echo the header and footer html. The javascript code then operates on the content div. Any php errors after this point go unseen or are hard to find. I am able to send an email of the error which is now my method of debugging - seems incorrect.

Here is my current error handler:

```
$message = "<p>Nice Job moron: A pos error occurred in script '$e_file' on line $e_line: $e_message\n<br />";
// Add the date and time:
$message .= "Date/Time: " . date('n-j-Y H:i:s') . "\n<br />";
// Append $e_vars to the $message:
$message .= "<pre>Error Variables:<br />" . print_r ($e_vars, 1) . "</pre>\n</p>";
// what is the url?
$message .= "<p><pre>URL: " .getPageURL()   . "</pre>\n</p>";
$message .= '<pre>Session variables:<br />' . print_r($_SESSION,1). "</pre>\n</p>";
$message .= '<pre>Bactrace:<br />' . print_r(debug_backtrace(),1). "</pre>\n</p>";
if (!LIVE) 
{ 
// Send an email to the admin:
    mail(SUPPORT_EMAIL, 'TEST Site Error!', $message, 'From: ' . SUPPORT_EMAIL);
    // Development (print the error).

    echo '<div class="error">' . $message . '</div><br />';


}
else 
{ 

    // Send an email to the admin:
    mail(SUPPORT_EMAIL, 'Site Error!', $message, 'From: ' . SUPPORT_EMAIL);
    // Only print an error message if the error isn't a notice:
    include(HEADER_FILE);
    if ($e_number != E_NOTICE) 
    {
        echo '<div class="error">A system error occurred. We apologize for the inconvenience.</div><br />';
    }
    echo '<div class="error">An Error has occurred and has been emailed to the administrator. Please note the conditions that caused this error and send a note to the administrator</div><br />';
}
```

Here is an error handler I found on stackoverflow from question [How to show all PHP runtime errors in browser using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358518/how-to-show-all-php-runtime-errors-in-browser-using-javascript/14358519#14358519) 
I would expect this to work, however it does not. It looks like script execution stops and no html rendering is happening.

```
//new error handling
$("#content").append('<p id="PHPError"> </p>');
$("#content").append('<button onclick="PHPErrors()">Show me all PHP runtime errors</button>'); 
var nerrors = 0;               // PHP Errors count in Javascript

function PHPErrors() 
{         
    // Javascript  Function that wraps the PHP Code
    <?php
        // MyErrorHandler is my function that my custom error handler
        // uses with error parameters in that given order.

         function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
         echo 'ERror';
         echo "document.getElementById('PHPError').innerHTML += " . 
          "\"$errno: $errstr ($errline)<br>\";\r\n";        
         echo "nerrors = nerrors + 1;\r\n";
         return true;
    }
    // That's the line the set my custom new error-handling
    // disabling the default error handling
    $old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

    // Below random PHP code full of errors 
    $b = $a;                 // PHP Error 1
    $c = $a +1;              // PHP Error 2
    $d = $a + 1;             // PHP Error 3  
    $e = $_SESSION['glove'];  // PHP Error 4
    ?>
    // No PHP runtime error deserves a nice messagen
    if (nerrors===0) 
    {
       document.getElementById('PHPError').innerHTML =
                        "Well done! PHP without errors."; 
    } 
}                        // End Javascript Function

$(document).ready(function()
{PHPErrors()});
```

Here is a long winded page source output. Ignoring some of the data and functions I see the Header and Footer output, then the script begins. It dies after a call to a php function with an undefined variable. I also note that my script tags are all over the place, might be a problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Create MFG Brand</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.embrasse-moi.com/POS_TEST/Engine/includes/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script>var POS_URL ='https://www.embrasse-moi.com/POS_TEST';</script><script>var LOGOUT_URL ='https://www.embrasse-moi.com/POS_TEST/Engine/login/logout.php';</script><script>POS_ENGINE_URL = "https://www.embrasse-moi.com/POS_TEST/Engine"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.embrasse-moi.com/POS_TEST/3rdParty/jQuery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="https://www.embrasse-moi.com/POS_TEST/3rdParty/jQueryUI/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.embrasse-moi.com/POS_TEST/3rdParty/jQueryUI/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.embrasse-moi.com/POS_TEST/Engine/includes/javascript/javascript_library.2015.06.02.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.embrasse-moi.com/POS_TEST/Engine/includes/javascript/check_login.2013.02.16.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:rgb(255,255,125);">
<div id="header" class =></div>
<div id="content" onmousemove ="UserInput()" onclick="UserInput()" onkeypress="UserInput()" onscroll="UserInput()"> 
<script src="brand.2015.08.03.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.embrasse-moi.com/POS_TEST/Engine/includes/javascript/mySQLTable.2015.08.04.js"></script>
</div><div id="footer">
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$("#content").append('<p id="PHPError"> </p>');
$("#content").append('<button onclick="PHPErrors()">Show me all PHP runtime errors</button>'); 
var nerrors = 0;               

function PHPErrors() 
{         
    ERrordocument.getElementById('PHPError').innerHTML += "8: Undefined variable: a (113)<br>";
    nerrors = nerrors + 1;
    ERrordocument.getElementById('PHPError').innerHTML += "8: Undefined variable: a (114)<br>";
    nerrors = nerrors + 1;
    ERrordocument.getElementById('PHPError').innerHTML += "8: Undefined variable: a (115)<br>";
    nerrors = nerrors + 1;
    ERrordocument.getElementById('PHPError').innerHTML += "8: Undefined index: glove (116)<br>";
    nerrors = nerrors + 1;
    if (nerrors===0) {
       document.getElementById('PHPError').innerHTML =
                        "Well done! PHP without errors."; } 
}                      

$(document).ready(function()
{PHPErrors()});

var type = "view";
var pos_manufacturer_id = 7;
var mfg_tbl_def = [json data sent by php];
var mfg_data = {json data from php};

var account_link = [json data from php];
var act_table_def = [json data from php];

var account_select_table_def = ERrordocument.getElementById('PHPError').innerHTML += "8: Undefined variable: table_object_name (285)<br>";
nerrors = nerrors + 1;
```

Comment: Is the extention of you javascript file that contains the php function '.php'? Otherwise you can't excecute php code within the file.

Comment: Yes, the file dumping the script is .php. Php tag is closed and script execution begins.

Comment: All reusable javascript is in .js file(s). The page specific javascript in done in .php. I used to build html strings in php, however found issues in closing div tags giving me an extra step of debugging html string. With this javascript approach I can create the div then append - WAY easier. However I still can't handle the php errors... tried many things... still stuck

Comment: Moving my php generation of the footer file to the end of the script allows the footer to fail upon php error and not display, so I know there is an error. Using my original error handler will show the error when I bring up page source. Still a bit silly but I can at least get the error. The new error handler will not show error.

Comment: Basically the same question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348252/php-runtime-error/14351468#14351468

Comment: There is apparently not a good solution other than sending an email