# How can I see errors in Xdebug in orange table in the browser?

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I have Xdebug and it's work well in the VSCode while debugging. But in the browser when I face an error it doesn't show the errors in the "orange table" to trace the errors to solve that.

What can I do to enable that?

I also show **xdebug_info()** here:

[image]

Comment: What's your Xdebug version? What's your Xdebug settings are? Please show `xdebug_info()` output.

Comment: I updated the question with xdebug_info output :)

Comment: If you run a code with `<?php $result = array_merge(1, 2);` -- will it report an error? It does that for me. The error: https://i.imgur.com/V3BFC5Z.png My Xdebug: https://imgur.com/0QqbXUn. Maybe it's PHP settings?.. What do you have for `display_errors`? Does it log it into the PHP's `error_log` file?

Comment: No, I just see this error: This page isn’t **project_name** is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: 1) Any frameworks? Try running that test code without framework -- any difference? 2) Could be specific to the web server used (e.g. it forces to show specific template response instead)... which one do you have? Mine code was run under IIS (I'm on Windows) 3) If it's one of the PHP settings -- show the whole "Core" section of `phpinfo()` output...

Comment: I just use php(pure)!!

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that you have set the `xdebug.mode` setting to just `debug`, which excludes Xdebug's other features, including, the orange errors. If you want to have both these enabled, set your `xdebug.mode` setting to `debug,develop`, instead of just `debug`.

Comment: my xdebug.mode is set both in debug and develop but i don't have yet!

Comment: Your xdebug_info() output disagrees, as it doesn't have "debug" ticked in the top section.

Comment: thanks, adding develop worked for me, this is a new feature of xdebug 3 isn't it ?

Comment: Thank You!!! Works great!! Your extension makes life a little bit more comfortable and modern :)

Answer (score 0):

first, make sure your `xdebug.mode` settings is `debug,develop` in `php.ini` or in `xdebug.ini` modules.

then, you can try to set `display_errors` and `display_startup_errors` to On in your `php.ini` file :

```
display_errors = On

display_startup_errors = On
```